# Does each apple developer has to pay $99 fee?

Tags: apple-developer

We have Apple Developer Account and we invited new guy,

does he have to pay $99 to become a member and get certificates?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about developer support/ customer service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share access with new guy I had to add him to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people/ , not only to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/users_roles